# Удаление выбранных строк из нескольких таблиц БД Access - C#

Tags: c#, база-данных, winforms, access

Здравствуйте. Решаю следующую задачу:
Имеется БД Access из двух связанных таблиц (связь один ко многим; одной строке таблицы1 соответствует несколько строк таблицы2). На форме два датагдида для отображения обоих таблиц БД.
Необходимо реализовать функцию удаления данных из БД (и соответственно из датагридов) работающую следующим образом: при удалении выбранной строки из главной таблицы (dataGridView1) также удалить и все связанные с ней строки из второй таблицы (dataGridView2).
Составил данный метод, но он удаляет через пень-колоду, логики в его удалениях не вижу(( В чём косяк?

```
private void buttonDeleteMainTable_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (MessageBox.Show("Удалить запись?", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            string str;
            str = Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value);//захват значения индекса записи из первой таблицы
            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView2.RowCount; i++)
            {
                if (dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString() == str)
                {
                    dataGridView2.Rows[i].Selected = true;
                    nameFirmModelParamBindingSource.RemoveCurrent();
                    model_ParamTableAdapter.Update(dataBaseMDBDataSet._Model_Param);
                }
            }
            nameFirmBindingSource.RemoveCurrent();
            name_FirmTableAdapter.Update(dataBaseMDBDataSet.Name_Firm);                
        }
    }
```

Comment: Используйте каскадное удаление связанных записей в свойствах связи. При удалении из таблицы на стороне "один" записи на стороне "много" удалятся без дополнительных телодвижений, сами...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос: Вы поставили галочку "каскадное удаление файлов"? Если нет, то при записи с главной таблице в самой же Access не удалиться связанная с ней запись.
Если я правильно понял, вы одну таблицу привязали к одному гриду, а вторую к другому.
Если это так, то достаточно в DataSet, который связан с обоими гридами, удалить строку из главной таблицы. При удалении удалиться и связанная запись в подчиненной.

Comment: Спасибо, попробую

Comment: Выдаёт исключение: System.InvalidOperationException: "Current item cannot be removed from the list because the list does not allow removal of items."

Comment: Можно поконкретнее? Как удаляете строку? На какой строке выдает исключение?

Answer (score 0):

Всё, разобрался. Спасибо Valery Losev за подсказку.

Вот код:

```
string str;
str = Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value);//захват значения индекса строки из первой таблицы
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.RowCount; i++)
{
    if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString() == str)
    {
        dataBaseMDBDataSet.Name_Firm.Rows[i].Delete();
        model_ParamTableAdapter.Update(dataBaseMDBDataSet._Model_Param);
        name_FirmTableAdapter.Update(dataBaseMDBDataSet.Name_Firm);
    }
}
```